# My php form will not submit through jQuery-Mobile

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery-mobile, submit-button

I have a fully working piece of PHP, HTML code but when I place it into my website that is styled using jQuery Mobile the submit button will not display the query. Does anybody know how to fix this or even why it is happening

SCRIPT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>The School of Computing and Mathematics</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/project1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
```

PHP

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<?php


// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'timetabledb');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$course_dropdown ="";
$query_course = "SELECT * FROM course";
$result_course = mysqli_query($con,$query_course) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_course))
{
$course_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['CourseName']}'>{$row['CourseName']}</option>";
} 

$module_dropdown ="";
$query_module = "SELECT * FROM module";
$result_module = mysqli_query($con,$query_module) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_module))
{
$module_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['ModuleName']}'>{$row['ModuleName']}</option>";
} 

$day_dropdown ="";
$query_day = "SELECT * FROM days ";
$result_day = mysqli_query($con,$query_day) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_day))
{
$day_dropdown .= "<option value='{$row['Day']}'>{$row['Day']}</option>";
} 


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>Course Name</th>
<th>Module Name</th>
<th>Type of Class</th>
<th>Lecturer</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Room</th>

</tr>";



if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Submit') {
   $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Course']);
$module = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Module']);
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Day']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM course_module WHERE CourseName = '$course' AND ModuleName = '$module' AND Day = '$day'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

 while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

 echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row1['CourseName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['ModuleName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['ClassType'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['Lecturer'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['Time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['Day'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row1['Room'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<h1>School of Computing and Mathematics</h1>
<h2>Mobile website<h2>
<h2>Current students</h2>

<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Timetabling</h3>
    <p>Select your Course</p>

    <form action="current.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <select name="Course">
    <option>Select Course</option>
    <?php echo $course_dropdown; ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Module">
    <option>Select Module</option>
    <?php echo $module_dropdown; ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Day">
    <option>Select Day</option>
    <?php echo $day_dropdown; ?>
    </select>

    <input id ="button_timetable" name="button" value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>





   </div>






<div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><a href="current.html">Current students</a></li>
        <li><a href="prospective.html">Prospective students</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
  </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that this script is fully implemented on a plain HTML site. I am only having issues with the jQuery mobile library.

Thank You in advance

Comment: And what about the MOST important part, javascript?

Comment: I havent used any javascript yet. What you can see above is the full code I am using.

Comment: Then why do you think this is a jQuery problem? You have used data-ajax="false" so normal form submit should work. First, have you checked for a successful request (did request reached PHP)? You haven't used ajax so I would guess there are't any PHP errors?

Comment: As I have said in the question, I have tested this exact code in a normal html file with no styling or js library meaning that the error is coming from one of the librarys. I assumed it was the jQuery Mobile as it is the only library that I have called any functions from

Comment: Then answer my other question, have you checked for a successful request (did request reached PHP)?

Comment: I does in the test file without jQuery Mobile, when using jQuery mobile it does not seem to reach the php nothing happens the page doesnt even refresh. But the button is being clicked i created an onclick function to test the button.

Comment: Lets do it like this, if it is not a problem, mail me both files and I will take a look. This must work.

Comment: yeah, how do you want me to mail the files

Comment: You will find my email address in my profile.

Comment: One last quesion, index.php or current.php is an original file whose form you want to submit?

Comment: yes @Gajotres it just submits to the original page. I do not want the form to change the page

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you an answer, I found everything going through your code.

Inside a index.php:

1. **data-ajax="false"** should be added as a form attribute, it prevents jQuery Mobile from using ajax to submit data.
2. Incorrect jQuery Mobile css was initialized in a HEAD
3. **table** tag was not closed

But, through and trough this is well built page.